# Training a 3 million sample data which has unbalanced labels

Tags: neural-networks, svm, deep-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, conv-neural-network

I have data which has 3 million samples and unbalanced label.

I have tried many neural network approaches, but I couldn't get a good result.

Which path do you suggest me to follow in this case, in order to be successful?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The main reason analysts have trouble with unbalanced cases is that they are using improper accuracy scoring rules in their optimization procedure.  If you try to use a probability estimation method (e.g., logistic regression) and you choose a proper objective function (e.g., the likelihood) you will not have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using stratified cross validation [1]. There are also some other suggestions such as in [2]. These of course don't guarantee success, but can be used to solve issues related to unbalanced labels.

1- [Understanding stratified cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation)

2- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133385/64720